# What's the best to get page URL in meta tag in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, href, meta-tags

So far I have the following tag in my header.php file

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>" />
```

And this seems to work, but it looks ugly to me and I'd like to make it as clean as possible. Will using `the_permalink()` give the exact same output for every page?

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
```

Comment: How about using javascript? `location.pathname`

Comment: What is the benefit to using javascript over server-side?

Comment: just a suggestion as you dont want to use `$_Server` i guess and are not sure about `the_permalink()`

Comment: @HarshMakani No, I was genuinely asking.. I don't use javascript if I can help it. So I was just wondering are there any upsides/downsides to using javascript over php

Comment: Well here, as vard said in his answer, you will have to do some processing before getting to your url. And as we know that wordpress updates a lot ( really a lot just in overnight :P ) so prefer to use javascript, which here will always provide you with precise url you want. Also javascript is client side and thus execution is faster than server side i guess?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with Wordpress functions, you can use [`home_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) by passing it the return of [`add_query_arg`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/), which used with an empty array will return a clean version of the current url.

```
echo home_url(add_query_arg(array()));
```

`the_permalink` is not reliable for this as it return the URL of the current post - it'll then not work properly on an archive page (it will return the permalink of the first post of the loop).

If you plan to use this few times, you may want to define a new function in *functions.php* like this:

```
function the_current_url() {
  echo home_url(add_query_arg(array()));
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="<?php the_current_url(); ?>" />
```